# Candidates: What are you going to do regarding Ron's suspension?

Tags: discussion, moderators

To all candidates to moderator: what are you going to do regarding Ron's suspension?

Comment: This is not an appropriate venue or topic for questioning the moderator candidates. As I've said elsewhere, we do not publicly discuss suspensions. If you have an issue with moderation actions performed on the site, take it up with the SE team, at team@stackexchange.com.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky could you please have a look at your mailbox? I have written you a mail, I am really horrified and thinking about leaving the SE network too ... :-(

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky this truly cannot stand.. if this becomes the norm I am sure I will be leaving as well.. honestly I expected something like this, but not until after the election.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Actually, I think this is an excellent question. Presently the candidates lack a bit of distinction in my eye. So I'd love to know how they would handle a similar case in the future. Also, you may not be at liberty to discuss some details of Ron's suspension, but the candidates surely are.

Comment: @jdm If it had been asked during the town hall chat (as a hypothetical scenario), that would have been fine.

Comment: Dear @DavidZaslavsky, are you serious? The town hall chat was immediately closed when Ron said that he had been suspended and I asked about that. And in particular, you said: "this is not the place to talk about that", or something very similar. Is this false?

Comment: As a candidate, I don't think they _can_ do anything at all.  And even if they get elected as a mod, I doubt they would be allowed to take on a community level mod...  It's a rhetorical question.  If I were a candidate, I would give Ron a unicorn.

Comment: @drake no, the town hall chat was not immediately closed when Ron said he was suspended. The chat was already over at that point. And as to the reason I said "this is not the place to discuss this," it would have been okay if asked _as a hypothetical scenario_. Not about an actual ongoing action.